# Upgrade Latest Version of R in Fedora 21

Tags: r, rstudio, fedora-21

I have an older version of R and Rstudio running in my Fedora 21. What is the command to upgrade to the latest version of R and Rstudio?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Fedora 21 is EOL. Update to supported version (which will probably get updated R).

Comment: See below — updated version will, in this case, _definitely_ get updated R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fedora 21 is no longer supported, reaching end-of-life on December 1st, 2015. However, the *current* version of Fedora contains — as of right now — R version 3.3.1, which is the latest. (It looks to be the case that R is kept pretty current if you're on the newest Fedora.)

Upgrading straight from Fedora 21 to Fedora 24 *might* work, but we officially only support skipping one release (so F22 to F24 definitely should). That's not much comfort now, but we've put a lot of work recently into making updates smooth and seamless, so you can basically take a little bit of time once or twice a year and hop to the new version — which should also keep you up to date with R. (For now, going from F21 to F22, and then F22 to F24 should do it.)

If this isn't a possibility for you, another option is to download the source RPM from Fedora 24 and rebuild it. This will Probably Work™.

Answer (score 0):

For lang.R Simply:

`yum update`

The FC21 official-repos have got the newest R-core &R-devel [Until today]

For R Studio:

Go to its official website and download its newest RPM package then

`rpm -ivh $thePackage`